# Matlab parpool on Intel Xeon-Phi (KNL)

Tags: matlab, parallel-computing

I am trying to run my matlab script on a Xeon Phi node with 68 physical cores. Using *parpool* I allocate 16 cores to enable SMD parallelization with a *parfor* loop. The script looks something like this.

```
parpool('local',16)
parfor i=1:N
    foo
end
```

When I run the script on Intel Xeon Phi processor (with MIC architecture), each MATLAB task uses only 6.5% CPU. There are no issues when I run on another machine with Intel Xeon processor (20 cores).
How can I get the maximum out of my computing resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`parpool`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html) is a part of [Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/index.html). According to [this discussion from 2015](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/243220-gpu-or-intel-xenon-phi-coprocessor) and [this discussion about Matlab2016a](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/293911-is-intel-xeon-phi-hardware-supported-by-the-parallel-computing-toolbox-in-the-last-releases-matlab), Parallel Computing Toolbox did not have a support for Intel Xeon Phi. However, at that time only Intel Xeon Phis on KNC architecture were available (that allowed only co-processor mode of operation).

I also was not able to find mentioning of Intel Xeon Phi in the current (R2018a) documentation.

And while KNL architecture is a huge step towards "a standalone CPU" (as compared to KNC), I guess Parallel Computing Toolbox might still have troubles with its full usage.

Comment: Indeed, I tried to get this working many times and it never did. The automatic offloading of BLAS works great, but [element-wise operations](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/261248-how-do-you-automatically-offload-elementwise-operations-to-the-xeon-phi) don't offload which left a lot of performance behind (and there were too many data transfers). Eventually I just gave up MATLAB since it works fine from Julia, and the serial code was much faster too meaning the multiplicative improvement of parallelism was pretty large.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas with Intel discontinuing this product line this summer, I guess, this question will not be too popular. What's funny, is the announcement of discontinuing came July 23, I answered July 24 and read the announcement July 25.

Comment: Yeah, it's sad because it did do a lot of things well, but was just very hard to use from MATLAB, Python, and R. It did get Julia's compilation tools to an interesting point where you can compile to other architectures, and that is now used in compiling functions to things like WebAssembly and TPUs, and transpilation to OpenCL was a nice way to get arrays working on the Xeon Phi, but indeed the original purpose for all of this will be forgotten. RIP.